# Trying to change background colour of an activity by clicking a checkbox on another activity

Tags: java, android

This is an app exercise, and I would appreciate some help and coding examples. I am trying to set the background colour from my SettingsActivity.java to my MainActivity.java. This would happen via a checkbox, that I click and triggers the change.

I can access MainActivity via intent, while the checkbox is clicked. However, if I try to set the colour of the MainActivity background Java throws a null pointer error, cause the value is null.

Here is the logcat:

```
01-05 16:28:58.612 22547-22547/com.smartdroidesign.fitnessassistant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                  Process: com.smartdroidesign.fitnessassistant, PID: 22547
                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                      at com.smartdroidesign.fitnessassistant.SettingsActivity$1.onCheckedChanged(SettingsActivity.java:52)
                                                                                      at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:156)
                                                                                      at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:115)
                                                                                      at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am pretty sure this is the line causing it:

```
mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
```

I am not too sure how to go from here, and still fairly new to Android, so I would appreciated some guidance/best practices.

So far I have tried to: instantiate the layout (Constraint layout) - bad idea, it seems, as it would leak
I have tried to use shared preferences, unsuccessfully.

Here is my MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public static final String SECOND_ACTIVITY_TITLE = "second.activity.title";
    public static final String THIRD_ACTIVITY_COLOR = "third.activity.color";
    public static final String EXCERCISE_WEIGHT = "Weight lifting";
    public static final String EXCERCISE_YOGA = "Yoga routine";
    public static final String EXCERCISE_CARDIO = "Cardio routine";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ConstraintLayout weightBtn = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.weightLayout);
        ConstraintLayout yogaBtn = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.yogaLayout);
        ConstraintLayout cardioBtn = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.cardioLayout);
        final ConstraintLayout mainAcBackground = findViewById(R.id.mainAcBackground);




        weightBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadDetailActivity(MainActivity.EXCERCISE_WEIGHT);

            }
        });

        yogaBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadDetailActivity(MainActivity.EXCERCISE_YOGA);

            }
        });

        cardioBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loadDetailActivity(MainActivity.EXCERCISE_CARDIO);

            }
        });
    }

    private void setSupportActionBar(Toolbar mToolbar) {
    }

    private void loadDetailActivity(String exerciseTitle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(MainActivity.SECOND_ACTIVITY_TITLE, exerciseTitle);
        startActivity(intent);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.settings, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.theme:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }






}
```

Here is my SettingsActivity (the one that is supposed to change the MainActivity background)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;


public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    ConstraintLayout mainAcBackground;
    public static final String ACTIVITY_COLOR = "color";








    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        Menu settings = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.action_setting);
        Menu theme = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.theme);
        final ConstraintLayout settingBG = findViewById(R.id.settingBG);
        final ConstraintLayout mainAcBackground = findViewById(R.id.mainAcBackground);
        final CheckBox nightMode = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.NightMode);






        nightMode.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (buttonView.isChecked()){
                    loadSettingsActivity(MainActivity.THIRD_ACTIVITY_COLOR);
                    mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

                }else {
                    mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadSettingsActivity(String exerciseTitle) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        startActivity(intent);
    }



    }
```

EDIT: here is the XLM for the MainActivity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainAcBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.smartdroidesign.fitnessassistant.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/weightLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#455A64"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/yogaLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/weight"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Day 1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Week 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/yogaLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#455A64"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cardioLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/weightLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:backgroundTint="#673AB7"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Day 2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Week 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/lotus"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cardioLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
        android:backgroundTint="#455A64"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yogaLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners"
            android:backgroundTint="#E53935"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Day 3"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="Week 1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="245dp"
            android:layout_height="74dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/heart"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the XML for the SettingsActivity

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/settingBG"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.smartdroidesign.fitnessassistant.SettingsActivity">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/NightMode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="35dp"
        android:text="Night mode"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Hope I have explained it clearly, let me know if you need more information, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Post the XMLs too please

Comment: Your problem is likely that the `mainAcBackground` simply doesn't exist at the time you try to set it. Try only storing the value in a variable and setting the background when you create the activity

Comment: @lucidbrot hmm, how would you go about it? Can I get a code example? Thanks you for your answer :)

Comment: @Memnoc a simple (but style-wise ugly) option would be a global static variable that contains the color you want to pass to `setBackgroundColor`. Then call `mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(yourGlobalVariable)` from your mainactivity's onCreate. (I don't have the time r/n to write a good answer, but this might already help enough)

Comment: @lucidbrot I have tried this approach back and forth a lot of times, but it does not seem to work, not sure why..I thought something was wrong with the whole approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `settingsActivity` from where you want to decide what color `mainAcBackground` will be in the main Activity.

Here's a simple approach, with untested code. But once that works, it shouldn't be hard to use `Intent.putExtra()` instead, or the `SharedPreferences`.

What the problem is: You cannot access a View in the main Activity from a different activity, because it will only exist once that Activity has been created. (As somebody new to android, you should probably read about the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html), which is often a source of confusion.) When your activity is loaded for the first time, `onCreate()` is called. When it is paused and later resumed, `onResume()` is called. In between, the setting for the background has maybe been changed by the user, so you want to set that background in the main activity's `onResume()`. That would look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  // Always call the superclass method first
    if(myBackgroundColor!=null){
        ConstraintLayout mainAcBackground = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainAcBackground);
        mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(myBackgroundColor);
    }
}
```

But how do you get your color into `myBackgroundColor`? 
In this approach, we're using a global variable for that because that is simple. So write in your main activity class

```
public static int myBackgroundColor;
```

You can access this variable from your settings activity with

```
MainActivity.myBackgroundColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)
```

in your `onCheckedStateChangedListener`.

Comment: This was a hell of an explanation, and it fixed my issue, thank you very much. Now, I am familiar with the Activity Lifecycle, but I have never grasped the real meaning of all of that up until now.

Comment: happy to help :) Interaction between activities is always initially confusing.
Please remember to upvote the answers that helped you and (after some time so that other people also have a chance to answer) accept one

Comment: I did vote but because this was my first post it will be recorded, but not displayed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious you can't change the background color of some activity from another one with simple storing the views reference not initialized.

here do something like this.

when you start setting activity from main activity start something like this

```
private void pickColor() {
    Intent settings = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(settings, 101);
}
```

and then you can change the color in settings activity and store the color code in intent and pass back to calling activity and finish the settings activity something like this.

```
public void colorChanged(int colorCode){
 Intent color = new Intent();
 color.putExtra("colorSelected",colorCode);
 setResult(RESULT_OK,color);
 finish();
}
```

and receive the results like this in main Activity which is your calling activity also.

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
   if(RESULT_OK==resultCode && requestCode==101){
   //here get the color as follows.
   int colorCode = data.getIntExtra("colorSelected");
   //here change the background

mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(colorCode);

}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I use this example, at mainAcBackground.setBackgroundColor(colorCode); it still asks me to initialize mainAcBackground and I am back to square 1.

Comment: yes you have to mainAcBackground belongs to main activity or the caller activity where you want to set the background so it should be there only not in some another class. and you will initialize it with findViewById in oncreate that's it.

Comment: Also, I do not "...start setting activity from main activity" it's the other way around. Here how it is supposed to work:
1 - I have a drop down in MainActivity
2 - I click on one of the option, and it brings me to SettingsActivity
3 - I click the checkbox to change the background of MainActivity
4 - The click brings me back via Intent to the MainActivity, that is supposed to have the background changed in the process. I just can't seem to be able to carry over the value

Comment: in mine case i am not starting another intent im just passing the intent to calling activity back to parent via setResult and finish the settings as soon settings finishes the main activity is behind it to catch the values in onActivityResult where you can set background i think it should work for your use case also. this is how i get values from another activity

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the `ConstraintLayout` with the ID `mainAcBackground` is in `activity_main.xml` and not in `activity_settings.xml`. If that's the case, 
`findViewById(R.id.mainAcBackground);` in `SettingsActivity.java` will return null and hence your `NullPointerException` is raised.

What you want to do is store the value in `SharedPreference` when your checkbox item changes and use that value in `MainActivity.java` to load the correct background color. You will have to use [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) in your `MainActivity.java` to ensure that when your activity is resumed, you can load the correct background.

Comment: Here's a tutorial for [`OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](http://envyandroid.com/android-detect-preference-changes/)

Comment: That is perfectly correct. The ConstraintLayout with the ID mainAcBackground is in activity_main.xml and not in activity_settings.xml
I have been on that tutorial already, but I could not get it to work. Would you mind providing a coding example? I must be doing something wrong, but thanks for the answer!